# How to tokenise list of integers in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a very long list of 195 different integers, but they range from 0 to 2399. For example the number 90 occurs many times, while the number 7 doesn't show up at all.

```
list = [90, 110, 113, 88, 90, 110, 90, 1370, 90]
```

I would like to 'tokenise' this, or turn it into a list of integers ranging from 0 to 195, while keeping the unique ID of the different values.

Basically, I'd like this output:

```
new_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1]
```

The goal is to be able to efficiently iterate over the list.

Comment: *efficiently iterate over the list*??? A number is a number. Iterating over larger numbers doesn't change anything

Comment: I don't really know why you want this, but you may want to use a hash. The integers (90, 110 ...) are the key. The value is the id. The first time you find a number, you increment a counter and store it in the hash and the new list. The next time you find a number, you use the id in the hash.

Comment: My two cents, usually when I hear "very long list" I think "trillions", not the price of a candy bar.

Comment: The problem is I don't know exactly what the 195 integers are, and I need to search the full (200.000) list for them. Reducing them from randomly spread between 0 and 2399 to 0-195 makes it easier. 

The hash solution sounds very nice, and most likely a more 'correct' way to do this. However, the solution proposed by Joran fixed my problem, and this is a one-time use script (for now).

The full list is just above 200.000, and the problem is I have to create identity matrixes based upon it. Reducing the complexity from 2399 different steps down to 195 is a massive performance gain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
d={}
new_list = [d[i] for i in values if d.setdefault(i,len(d)+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

As @cricket_007, I question your application.  Iteration doesn't vary with the magnitude of the number.  However, if you have  reason to need a dense set of IDs, then this is one possible solution.  I've left the building loop simple to let you see how it works; there are some Pythonic improvements you could make, such as using the dictionary **get** method.

Build a dictionary to translate old to new IDs.
Then do the translation in one fell swoop.

```
my_list = [90, 110, 113, 88, 90, 110, 90, 1370, 90]

new_id_dict = {}
new_id = 0

for id in my_list:
    if id not in new_id_dict:
        new_id += 1
        new_id_dict[id] = new_id

new_list = [new_id_dict[id] for id in my_list]
print new_list
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1]
```

Comment: Ha!  @Joran did a lovely minimalist version while I was adding that comment about improvements.

Comment: Using @ in answers doesn't really do anything, AFAIK